# Merge two data files in SAS and create variables

Tags: variables, merge, sas, left-join

I have two datasets to join and pull the details from the first table as two variables

Here are my two datasets

```
 data1

  ID          Code      last4_Code
 101        102345678      5678
 101        234142345      2345
 101        189765412      5412
```

The second dataset is a single row per id with two codes (`code1 and code2`)

```
data2

  ID          code1      code2 
 101          5678       5412
```

I need my final dataset with `code' from first dataset as two different variables

```
 ID          Code1_a       Code2_a
101         102345678     189765412
```

I tried `proc sql` left join to get the multiple rows and then create two new variables

```
   proc sql;
    create table new as select
     a.id,b.code from
     data2 a
     left join data1 b
     on a.id=b.id
     or a.code1=b.last4_code
   quit;
```

but this is not working as expected.

I would appreciate any help !!

Comment: You're looking for a variable called `code1` in alias `a`, i.e. `data1`, but in your example dataset you only have one called `code`. Similarly you're looking for `last4_code` in alias `b` i.e.`data2` but that variable is in `data1`, not `data2`.

Answer (score 0):

something like this. you need to do join for both conditions for code1 and code2 and tie them back

```
data have1;

input ID          Code      last4_Code;
datalines;
101        102345678      5678
101        234142345      2345
101        189765412      5412
 ;

data have2;

input ID          Code1      code2;
datalines;
101          5678       5412
 ;


 proc sql;
 select coalesce(x.id,y.id) as id, code1_a format=best32., code2_a format   
=best32. from 
 ( select a.id, code as code1_a from
 have1 a
inner join
have2 b
on b.code1 = a.last4_code)x
full join 
(select a.id, code as code2_a from
have1 a
inner join
have2 b
on b.code2 = a.last4_code)y
on x.id =y.id;
```

Instead of have1 has one record for last4_Code in the earlier example, if you have multiple last4_Code values also the above code will work. try the above code with below table too.

```
/*this has an additional line of data*/
 101        102545669      5678*/

 data have1;

  input ID          Code      last4_Code;
  datalines;
   101        102345678      5678
  101        234142345      2345
  101        189765412      5412
  101        102545669      5678
 ;
```

Comment: Can I take have2 as my base as this doesn't have duplicate ids. The above code is producing multiple rows which also includes second record from have2 for which there is no last 4 match in have1

Comment: what you want to see if you have duplicates a null value. sure

Comment: if null in have1 then just blank as there is no match. Its rare that I see duplicates in have1 for have2 ids - even if they exist, I just need rows with duplicate codes from have1